# How to vectorize if statement when several statements are affected?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to vectorize my python code.

I am able to replace a simple `if` statement in an elegant way, if there is just one statement that should be executed afterwards:

```
if a < b:
    c = 5
```

gets to:

```
c = np.where(a<b,5,c)
```

Is there any elegant way of vectorisation, if there are a lot of statements that follow the `if` statement?:

```
if a y b:
    c = 5
    d = 6
    e = 7
    f = 8
    .... 
    z = 99
```

I would like to avoid having a lot similar (somehow unpythonic) statements like:

```
c = np.where(a<b,5,c)
d = np.where(a<b,6,c)
e = np.where(a<b,7,c)
f = np.where(a<b,8,c)
.... 
z = np.where(a<b,99,c)
```

It does not seem possible to use tuples for `np.where` or am I wrong?

Comment: I don't see any loop. What exactly are you trying to vectorize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
ind = c[np.repeat([b>a],c.shape[0],axis=0)]
c[np.repeat([b>a],c.shape[0],axis=0)] = np.repeat(d,int(ind.shape[0]/d.shape[0]))
```

where `c` is an array of the shape `(number of statements, length of a)` (It can be initialised with `np.zeros((number of statements, length of a))` for example) and `d` is the array of values (`[5,6,7,8..99]`).